# radius unit in Pressure vs radius graph

Tags: pressure, astrophysics, units, si-units, unit-conversion

In the TOV equation of state of neutron star if we take central pressure and central energy density in Mev/fm^3, then in what will be the unit of radius in the graph of pressure vs radius. Usual we expect radius from 5-15 km but in this case pressure is taken in Mev/fm^3, what may be the expected range of radius and in what unit.

Answer (score 0):

Physics does not depend on units. Pressure and energy density have the dimension energy per volume and radius has the dimension length. $\mathrm{MeV/fm}^{-3}$ is a valid unit with the correct dimensions for pressure and energy density and km is a valid unit for lengths.

For neutron stars (NS) those units are well suited because radii of NS are typically around $10$ $\mathrm{km}$, central pressures are typically between $10$ and $500$ $\mathrm{MeV/fm}^{-3}$ and energy densities are between $100$ and $1000$ $\mathrm{MeV/fm}^{-3}$. The exact values strongly depend on the individual NS and its equation of state.

Comment: Km is a SI unit but as I mentioned above, if we take pressure and energy density in  Mev/fm^3 then what the dimension of radius I would get in the   graph  of Pressure vs radius or energy vs radius.will it be in km or in some fm.